# iPhone / iPad disables interaction with links after Javascript scroll on page

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, ipad

I am using a Javascript to have a link in my fixed header scroll the view down to a certain place on the page. Just an animated scroll basically.

When the page loads, all is fine and the link scrolls the page down. From then on, the buttons in the header do not work until the page in manually scrolled, even a tiny amount, by the user. After the content had been moved by the user, all the buttons work again.

Works as expected on Windows 7 using IE9, Chrome, FF, Safari and Opera; fails on Samsung GT-I9000 Android 2.6.32.9; fails on iPad and iPhone with iOS 5.1.1.

Any ideas? Thanks.